# mysql tuple comparison not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples

i have a question concerning the comparison of tuples in mysql.

I have two tables:

```
Person_ID | Class_ID | STATE
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 3 | 0

Person_ID | Class_ID
1 | 1 
1 | 2  
1 | 3
```

Thus, the second row is not existing in the first table. However, I want to combine the tables like:

```
Person_ID | Class_ID | STATE
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | -1
1 | 3 | 0
```

Someone an idea, how I can do that?

I tried to play with exist, if, where, etc. :-(.

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t2.Person_ID, t2.Class_ID,
       COALESCE(t1.STATE,-1) AS STATE
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 
   ON t2.Person_ID = t1.Person_ID AND t2.Class_ID = t1.Class_ID
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.

it results the same as my tests. Now all tuples have the state -1... What can i do. It should be like:

if tuple(A,B) in table1 and table2 than State is as given, otherwise it is -1...

Comment: @HeikoAngermann The query should give you the expected result. If it fails, then can you please explain where it does?

Comment: sry it was my mistake. It works fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @HeikoAngermann Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.